# Find duplicate in array - Time complexity < O(n^2) and constant extra space O(1). (Amazon Interview)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Given below is the problem statement and the solution. I am not able to grasp the logic behind the solution.

**Problem Statement:**
Given an array nums containing n + 1 integers where each integer is between 1 and n (inclusive), prove that at least one duplicate number must exist. Assume that there is only one duplicate number, find the duplicate one.

Note:
You must not modify the array (assume the array is read only).
You must use only constant, O(1) extra space.
Your runtime complexity should be less than O(n2).
There is only one duplicate number in the array, but it could be repeated more than once.

Sample Input: [3 4 1 4 1]
Output: 1

The **Solution** for the problem posted on leetcode is:

```
class Solution(object):
    def findDuplicate(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        low = 1
        high = len(nums)-1

        while low < high:
            mid = low+(high-low)/2
            count = 0
            for i in nums:
                if i <= mid:
                    count+=1
            if count <= mid:
                low = mid+1
            else:
                high = mid
        return low
```

**Explanation for the above code (as per the author)**:
This solution is based on binary search.

At first the search space is numbers between 1 to n. Each time I select a number mid (which is the one in the middle) and count all the numbers equal to or less than mid. Then if the count is more than mid, the search space will be [1 mid] otherwise [mid+1 n]. I do this until search space is only one number.

Let's say n=10 and I select mid=5. Then I count all the numbers in the array which are less than equal mid. If the there are more than 5 numbers that are less than 5, then by Pigeonhole Principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) one of them has occurred more than once. So I shrink the search space from [1 10] to [1 5]. Otherwise the duplicate number is in the second half so for the next step the search space would be [6 10].

***Doubt:*** In the above solution, when `count <= mid` , why are we changing `low` to `low = mid + 1` or otherwise changing `high = mid` ? ***What's the logic behind it?***

**I am unable to understand the logic behind this algorithm**

Related Link:
https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/25580/two-solutions-with-explanation-o-nlog-n-and-o-n-time-o-1-space-without-changing-the-input-array

Comment: `[3 4 1 4 1]` has two duplicates, 1 and 4.

Comment: Actually this code tolerates more than one duplicate, and outputs the smallest one.

Comment: Yes, if there are multiple duplicates it will output any one of them.

Comment: If `nums` has n+1 numbers between 1 and n, and only one duplicate, then the duplicate one is just `sum(nums)-(n*(n+1))/2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it's a binary search. You are cutting the search space in half and repeating.

Think about it this way: you have a list of 101 items, and you know it contains values 1-100. Take the halfway point, 50. Count how many items are less than or equal to 50. If there are more than 50 items that are less than or equal to 50, then the duplicate is in the range 0-50, otherwise the duplicate is in the range 51-100.

Binary search is simply cutting the range in half. Looking at 0-50, taking midpoint 25 and repeating.

---

The crucial part of this algorithm which I believe is causing confusion is the for loop. I'll attempt to explain it. Firstly note that there is **no usage of indices** anywhere in this algorithm - just inspect the code and you'll see that index references do not exist. Secondly, note that the algorithm loops through the entire collection for each iteration of the `while` loop.

Let me make the following change, then consider the value of `inspection_count` after every `while` loop.

```
inspection_count=0
for i in nums:
    inspection_count+=1
    if i <= mid:
        count+=1
```

Of course `inspection_count` will be equal to `len(nums)`. The for loop iterates the entire collection, and for every element checks to see whether it is within the candidate range (of values, not indices).

The duplication test itself is simple and elegant - as others pointed out, this is the pigeonhole principle. Given a collection of `n` values where every value is in the range `{p..q}`, if `q-p < n` then there must be duplicates in the range. Think of some easy cases -

```
p = 0, q = 5, n = 10
"I have ten values, and every value is between zero and five.
At least one of these values must be duplicated."
```

We can generalize this, but a more valid and relevant example is

```
p = 50, q = 99, n = 50
"I have a collection of fifty values, and every value is between fifty and ninety-nine.
There are only forty nine *distinct* values in my collection.
Therefore there is a duplicate."
```

Comment: Let's shrink the size for ease:
Let, N = 10.

N+1 ( = 11) integers in the array are:
[9,7,6,8,10,5,2,4,1,1,3].

Halfway point, mid = 5.
**6 elements (5,2,4,1,1,3) are less than or equal to mid (= 5).**

Now Sir, according to your answer if there are more than 5 items that are less than or equal to 5 then duplicate will lie in range in 0-5. **But here duplicate is in range 6-11.**

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @kshikhar Correcting you: the duplicate is 1, it is in the range 1..5. We are talking about the range of values, not indices. You are not asked to find the index of the duplicate, but its value. The algorithm doesn't ever look at indices. It doesn't matter where in the array the two 1s are.

Comment: @kshikhar as above comment says, we don't look at positions. We have to repeatedly loop through the entire collection to count the items that fall within some range. Worst case we will be looping through n items n times, i.e. O(n^2).

Comment: @n.m. 
_We are talking about the range of values, not indices. You are not asked to find the index of the duplicate, but its value_ 
I understood this part. Now, we know that duplicate will lie between 1...5
But how come here we are able to find the duplicate through indices?
Aren't we suppose to find duplicate using values in the array only, and not indices? I mean, we are finding duplicate number using indices, what's the **connection** b/w them?

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst Yes. Please see my above comment.

Comment: `But how come here we are able to find the duplicate through indices?` - we aren't. Ready my first comment. We loop through every item and count those that have values in the given range. We don't consider indices at all.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst O(n^2) in the worst case — are you sure? Because that's not allowed. Isn't it O(n log(n)) in all cases?

Comment: It says O(n2), not O(nlogn)

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst The question says it has to be less than O(n^2) and you say worst case is O(n^2). What are you referring to?

Comment: @Andreas you said `Because that's not allowed.`. But it is, per the question, as you noted. Will it run O(n^2) or O(nlogn)? Thinking through I guess there shouldn't be more than logn loops.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst I only noted that the solution has to be < O(n^2) which — I thought — implied that it's not allowed to be = O(n^2). I don't know why a O(n^2) solution would be acceptable in that case. But then again it was a long time since I had to use O-notation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128757/discussion-between-kirk-broadhurst-and-andreas).

Comment: @Andreas algorithm is not allowed to be = O(N^2) . Time complexity should be **less than O(N^2)**

Comment: In the example which you have taken in your answer, 50 refers to the index of the array or the element in the array whose value = 50 ?? Because, in the algorithm above mid refers to the index of the array.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst

Comment: @kshikhar  "find the duplicate through indices" which indices? where do you see an index in the code?

Comment: The worst case is not O(n^2), it's O(n log n).

Comment: @kshikhar Yes, I know. It's the point I've been making all along, which you'll see if you read all my comments.

Comment: @kshikhar no, it does not refer to the index. You should study the algorithm further. There is no use of indexes in this algorithm. It is confusing because normally this pattern applies to indexes, but that is the entire point of the question.

Comment: At least @n.m. seems to agree.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst " _It is confusing because normally this pattern applies to indexes, but that is the entire point of the question_  ." So this pattern is being applied on numbers only from range 1 to N, as given in the problem statement, right?

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst brilliant explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The logic behind setting `low = mid+1` or `high = mid` is essentially what makes it a solution based on [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). The search space is divided in half and the `while` loop is searching only in the lower half (`high = mid`) or the higher half (`low = mid+1`) on its next iteration.

> So I shrink the search space from [1 10] to [1 5]. Otherwise the duplicate number is in the second half so for the next step the search space would be [6 10].

This is the part of the explanation regarding your question.

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have 10 numbers.

```
a=[1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

then mid=5
and the number of elements that are less than or equal to 5 are 6 (1,2,2,3,4,5).
now count=6 which is greater than mid. this implies that there is atleast one duplicate in the first half so what the code is doing is making the search space to the first half that is from [1-10] to [1-5] and so on.
Else a duplicate occurs in second half so search space will be [5-10].

Do tell me if you have doubts.

Comment: Problem statement says you can only use O(1) of extra space -- this uses O(n).

Comment: sometimes people downvote without even giving a thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void findDuplicateInArrayTest() {

    int[] arr = {1, 7, 7, 3, 6, 7, 2, 4};

    int dup = findDuplicateInArray(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);

    System.out.println("duplicate: " + dup);
}

public static int findDuplicateInArray(int[] arr, int l, int r) {

    while (l != r) {

        int m = (l + r) / 2;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            if (arr[i] <= m)
                count++;

        if (count > m)
            r = m;
        else
            l = m + 1;
    }
    return l;
}
```